# Facebook API - Re-Size Feed Picture

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using the feed api to post status messages with pictures.  I do a post with parameters like:

```
message:  'My Message'
picture:  'https://......./myimage.png'
caption:  'this is my caption'
height:   '150' #ignored
width:    '300' #ignored
type:     'status' #ignored
```

Is there way to post a picture and scale it so its a little larger?    I tried passing parameters to it with no luck.. I noticed most of my posts were being created with types as "link."

Comment: I do not believe there is a way to do this.  At least not a documented way.  From what I have gathered it depends on the quality/size of the picture and how many have been posted.  When a user uploads several pictures to an album (possibly even though an application), Facebook deals with the layout in the news feed in a different way than when a single picture is uploaded spreading the images out.  It could also be related to an odd or even number of images...

Comment: I am passing an external URL to the picture argument, just an FYI.  I am not using "facebook photos."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this is no.  If you want to be able to reference a picture, and resize it then you need to actually post a picture  and set the captions on that.